# Question Regarding the Replacement Schema

Tags: set-theory, axioms

For each formula $\phi(x,y,p)$, we have the following axiom:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (\phi(x,y,p) \wedge \phi(x,z,p) \rightarrow y = z) \rightarrow \forall X \exists Y \forall y (y \in Y \leftrightarrow (\exists x \in X) \phi(x,y,p))$

This set of axioms has been characterized informally in English as follows:

"If a class $F$ is a function, then for every set $X$, $F(X)$ is a set."

But isn't the English statement saying *much less* than what the actual schema is saying?  That is, it seems that the schema can be interpreted as saying what the English statement is saying only if we interpret $\phi(x,y,p)$ as being the property of "$y$ is the image of $x$ under $p$".  But then aren't there many more interpretations of $\phi(x,y,p)$ that might permit this axiom schema to be saying some radically different things than this?  In any event, how should one interpret formulae of the sort $\phi(x,y,p)$ as above?

Comment: It's not $p$ that is the function. $p$ is a constant that is used to define a function via $\phi$. The point is that $\phi$ defines a functional relation in the universe.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think it only makes sense with "$y$ is the image of $x$ under $p$".

The first part $\forall x \forall y \forall z (\phi(x,y,p) \wedge \phi(x,z,p) \rightarrow y = z)$ defines a class function $F_p$ by saying $F_p(x)=y$ whenever $\phi(x,y,p)$ holds.

The second part
$\forall X \exists Y \forall y (y \in Y \leftrightarrow (\exists x \in X) \phi(x,y,p))$ then says there is a set $Y$ such that $Y=\{y : \exists x,\phi(x,y,p)\} = F_p(X)$.

Comment: How does one get from $\forall x \forall y \forall z (\phi(x,y,p) \wedge \phi(x,z,p) \rightarrow y = z)$ to the class function $F_p$ defined by $F_p(x)=y$ whenever $\phi(x,y,p)$ holds?  That is, I'm confused about how us talking about the arbitrary formulas $\phi(x,y,p)$ and $\phi(x,z,p)$  allows us to talk about functions?

Comment: The statement $\forall x \forall y \forall z (\phi(x,y,p) \wedge \phi(x,z,p) \rightarrow y = z)$ is a sort of injectivity property on the property $\phi$. Recall what it means for a set $f$ to be a function. Say $f:X\to Y$, then it means $f \subset X \times Y$ such that for every $x \in X$, there is a unique $y \in Y$ with $(x,y) \in f$. In particular, if $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$ then $y=z$. Do you see how this is the same injectivity property? The only difference is that for $F_p$ we aren't working inside a set, so we use universal quantification and make the CLASS function $F_p$.

Comment: Yes I see the structural similarity between the definition of a function and the "sort of injectivity property on the property $\phi$".  My question, though, is how we go from talking about an arbitrary property $\phi(x,y,p)$ to a "class function" $F_p$?  What does an arbitrary formula named $\phi$ have to do with a class function?  Why do we just assume that $\phi$ is being used to define a class function?

Comment: We aren't assuming $\phi$ is being used to define a class function.  From a given $\phi$ we are *constructing* a class function by saying $F_p(x) = y$ whenever $\phi(x,y,p)$ holds. Likewise, given a class function, we may recover a property by saying $\phi(x,y,p)$ holds if $F_p(x)=y$. This gives a bijection between class functions $F$ and properties $\phi$, so that no information is lost by changing viewpoints from property $\phi$ to class function $F$ or vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

Let me point the problem, and it is also a mistake in your formulation of the axiom:

Your $p$ is a free variable. It should be $\forall p( \ldots )$, where the dots represent your stated axiom. In fact, it should be $\vec p$, because we may have several parameters. This means that whenever we have fixed the parameter and the result is functional, then the image of a set is a set.

The informal gist of the axiom is the same, because we don't specify whether or not $F$ is definable with parameter, without parameters, and so on. We just say that $F$ is a formula. An even more correct formulation would to say that $F$ is a *definable* formula.

So the axiom says that if $F$ is a formula definable from parameters $p$. Of course we can change the parameters and have another function. Completely different one too.